# Gerar gráficos de contornos sobre um mapa de 360*360 posições com pesos de 0 a 1

Tags: matplotlib, gráfico-condicional

Qual técnica posso utilizar para gerar gráficos no estilo do **c** e **d** dessa figura?

[image: estilo c e d]

Meu *input* vai ser no padrão: X, Y e o peso dessa posição, onde X e Y vão de -180° até 180°, e o peso varia de 0 a 1 utilizando 6 casas decimais, [esse é o exemplo1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n72eukz2ajti20l/A_H_histogram.dat) [esse é o exemplo 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jcfywyhkqtuw8sw/G_H_histogram.dat).

Esse arquivo é criado a partir do código de mapa de densidade, [encontrado aqui](http://pelican.rsvs.ulaval.ca/mediawiki/index.php/Making_density_maps_using_Gnuplot).

Já testei com o GNUplot utilizando `pm3d map` e o `pm3d interpolate`, porém eu não consegui gerar os contornos por ser um gráfico muito espaço talvez...

Também tentei utilizar o `matplotlib` com `pcolormesh` aplicando `levels` e depois aplicando o `countor` ou `countorf`, utilizando [este link como base](http://matplotlib.org/examples/images_contours_and_fields/pcolormesh_levels.html).

Ou seja, eu consigo gerar gráficos assim:
[image: Utilizando o GNUplot]

Com `matplotlib` eu tentei utilizando o código a seguir:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import scipy.ndimage
import numpy as np

def make_colormap(seq):
    seq = [(None,) * 3, 0.0] + list(seq) + [1.0, (None,) * 3]
    cdict = {'red': [], 'green': [], 'blue': []}
    for i, item in enumerate(seq):
        if isinstance(item, float):
            r1, g1, b1 = seq[i - 1]
            r2, g2, b2 = seq[i + 1]
            cdict['red'].append([item, r1, r2])
            cdict['green'].append([item, g1, g2])
            cdict['blue'].append([item, b1, b2])
    return mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap('CustomMap', cdict)

f = open("~/histogramaGLY.dat","r")
k = [[0 for x in xrange(359)] for x in xrange(359)] 
while 1:
    line = f.readline()
    if not line: break      
    line2 = ''.join(line).split()
    k[int(float(line2[0]))][int(float(line2[1]))] = float(line2[2])
f.close()
k = scipy.ndimage.zoom(k, 4)
z = np.array(k)

dx, dy = 0.25, 0.25

y, x = np.mgrid[slice(-180, 179 + dx, dx),
        slice(-180, 179 + dy, dy)
                ]
levels = MaxNLocator(nbins=1000).bin_boundaries(z.min(), z.max())

c = mcolors.ColorConverter().to_rgb
rvb = make_colormap(
    [c('white'), 0.05, c('cyan'), 0.1, c('blue'), 0.15, c('darkblue'), 0.2,  c('green'), 0.2,  c('lightgreen'), 0.3, c('yellow'), 0.4, c('red'), 0.5, c('darkred')])
N = 256

plt.contourf(x[:-1, :-1],
             y[:-1, :-1], k, levels=levels,
             cmap=rvb)
plt.show()
```

gerando esse gráfico:

[image: Utilizando o MatPlotLib]

Porém, não consigo gerar o efeito utilizado na figura 1.

Como fazer o efeito de `smoothing` ou `countor` que a primeira foto apresenta, sabendo que são 129600 linhas para interpolar?

Comment: Olá. Eu creio que o caminho deve ser esse mesmo: usar `countorf`. O seu resultado tá quase lá, na verdade. Ele provavelmente parece granulado porque o seu volume de dados é bastante discreto (pequeno). Talvez se você aumentar a massa de dados interpolando valores intermediários o resultado fique mais "bonito". Se você puder editar a questão para postar o código que já tem (e os dados), eu posso tentar fazer uns testes por aqui com essa ideia.

Comment: Alterei o post, vejá o que eu consegui até agora e o padrão de entrada que eu uso.

Comment: Então, eu olhei o seu código e até testei por aqui (com os dados que você forneceu na sua pergunta) e não vi problema. De fato, eu obtive um resultado bem diferente do seu, embora sem o granulado. Vide [essa imagem](http://imgur.com/hFz71FA,xoraiV5#0) e também [essa outra](http://imgur.com/hFz71FA,xoraiV5#1) (zoom da primeira na região com os dados). P.S.: estou usando o Python 2.7.6 no Windows 8, com Matplotlib 1.3.1, numpy 1.8.0 e scipy 0.13.2

Comment: Certo, pra esse exemplo1 de entrada o zoom realmente ajuda na hora da análise. O problema é quando tenho arquivos do tipo do exemplo2(adicionei ele agora), esse mostra pontos mais espalhados no mapa, causando o efeito de granulado. Esse é o problema que ainda não consegui contornar. Alguma ideia??

Comment: Cara, no exemplo 2 aparece alguns pontos "granulados" próximo da área de interesse (canto superior direito), mas mesmo assim tá bem longe do que você tem na sua imagem. Não é ruído no arquivo de dados não? Aliás eu vi só agora que você já faz um ajuste com `scipy.ndimage.zoom(k, 4)`. Bom, desculpe, mas não tenho mais sugestões a respeito.

Comment: Então posta uma resposta para a tua própria pergunta e aceita ela logo após isso...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvi utilizar os dados reais mesmo, sem interpolar, mas consegui contornar o problema utilizando uma interpolação inicial sobre os dados de entrada e utilizando o interpolate 0,0 no GNUPlot. Editei o texto e já mudei para resolvido meu problema.

Primeiramente eu mudei a geração dos dados de entrada, utilizando uma interpolação de 4x4 e depois apliquei o comando "set pm3d map interpolate 0,0" do `GNUPlot`, assim utilizando o padrão 0,0 o próprio `GNUPlot` escolhe a melhor interpolação dos dados.

Segue abaixo a diferença de sem interpolar e interpolando os dados.
[image: Resultado sem interpolação(Bastante Dados)]
[image: Resultado com interpolação dos dados + interpolate do GNUPlot(Bastante Dados)]

Abaixo segue o resultado utilizando poucos dados de entrada.
[image: Resultado sem interpolação(Poucos Dados)]
[image: Resultado com interpolação dos dados + interpolate do GNUPlot (Poucos Dados)]

Porém a desvantagem interpolando os dados é que eu acabo perdendo detalhes, que no meu caso não são ruídos, então acredito que vou utilizar os dados sem interpolar mesmo.

Comment: Já pensou em interpolar usando algum critério logaritmico? Assim você teria resultados mais "smooth" nas partes densas, e ao mesmo tempo não deixaria de ver os pontos esparsos (uma coisa mais ou menos assim: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uThQf.png )